# What is the difference between country and region translation in android translations editor

Tags: android, android-studio, translation, translation-editor

I am currently translating my android app via the embedded translations editor of android studio. Within the locale menu, I could either choose a general language or a language/dialect connected to a specific country. For instance German (de) or German (de) in Austria (at) or German (de) in Belgium (Be) etc..
In case I would like to reach users in all Spanish speaking countries, is it enough to add just a general Spanish locale in my values-es folder or should I create a Spanish locale for each hispanophone country? The second option would not make sense to me, especially since the app is not that complex, that it has to support dialects or varieties.

Comment: I think that You don't have to "override" all Spanish languages. If You make a file for the Spanish language and a user has set Spanish-Argentina (sp-AR) in a phone, language Spanish will be selected. But the phone first will check if there is an "sp-AR" and then check "es". Phone try to find the best language

Comment: @iknow all right thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

In the `Project`, at the left side, select option `Project Files`, so one can see the directory structure of the current project.

Under the `res` directory, there is a folder `values...` for each desired language and country combination, and within each one there is a `strings.xml` file created. That files should contain all the words translated in the related language.

The simplest way is to initially create a general file with the Spanish language (es): it would be the `values-es` folder  (created by right clicking mouse on the `res` directory, option, then `new`, `Android Resource Directory` and selecting the Spanish language.

After one should create a new empty `strings.xml` file, created under this new folder (`value-es`) Right mouse click in the new folder, select option `new`, `Values Resource File`, named it `strings.xml`.

This file will contain all the words in your app, under the common general structure, that should be in each `strings.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <-!--strings-->
</resources>
```

However, there are some cases that will be exceptions and you will need to create more specific files. Let's assume the one needs the app for Chile.  So it to be created a new folder. Also use `new`, `Android Resource Director`, and choose Spanish and Chile. The new folder will be called `values-es-rCL`. Under this folder, one needs to create other empty `Strings.xml` with the above initial content.

This file will be almost empty

Howeever there are exceptions: `savories` is `tapa` in Spain, but in Chile is `picoteos`.

If default language is English put:

Under `values` folder in `strings.xml`:
savories

Under `values-es` folder in `strings.xml`:
tapas

Under `values-es-rCL` folder in `strings.xml`:
picoteos

So where appear `savories`, the app searchs in specific country (`values-es-rCL`), if it didn't find, it search in language (`values-es`),if  it also didn't find, it search in default language (`values`)

For a normal word, like `tap`, it just necessary put the word `grifo` in spanish language, with no worry about chilean `strings.xml`

if someone needs  to be compatible with Mexico, then it will be necessary to create `strings.xml` and the folder `values-mx-rMX` for this "dialect". local translatio for 'savories' is the word `botanas`